# Como impedir uma variável de ficar negativa em Java?

Tags: java, int

Estou fazendo um aplicativo para Android no Android Studio no qual existe uma lista de itens, onde pode escolher aumentar ou diminuir a quantidade de cada item, então para isso criei dois botões para cada item, um para aumentar e outro para diminuir a quantidade, segue modelo:

```
int quantity_item;

public void increment_item(View view) {
    quantity_item = quantity_item + 1;
    display_item(quantity_item);

}

public void decrement_item(View view) {
    quantity_item = quantity_item - 1;
    display_item(quantity_item);
}
```

O problema é que quando o valor é zero e clica no botão `decrement_item`, o valor fica negativo. Como faço para impedir isso? Como faço para quando estiver em "0", ao apertar `decrement_item`, nada aconteça?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente crie uma condição que impeça isto:

```
public void decrement_item(View view) {
    if (quantity_item > 0) {
        quantity_item--;
        display_item(quantity_item);
    }
}
```

Também poderia fazer algo assim para informar melhor:

```
public void decrementItem(View view) {
    if (quantityItem > 0) {
        quantityItem--;
        displayItem(quantityItem);
    } else {
        messagemErro("Não pode ficar com valor inferior a zero");
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Validation2.java).

Comment: Escrevei dessa maneira:

`código
int quantity_item;
public void increment_item(View view)  { 
    quantity_item = quantity_item + 1; 
    display_item(quantity_item);

     }

public void decrement_item(View view) { 
    quantity_item = quantity_item - 1; 
    if (quantity_item > 0) { 
        quantity_item--;
        display_item(quantity_item); 
        }

    }`

Porém, depois que aumento a quantidade, se tento diminuir, no primeiro clique nada acontece, no segundo, diminui duas unidades. O que fiz de errado?

Comment: isto está relacionado a outra questão, o que mudou aí é apenas impedir o número ficar negativo, mais nada, que foi o pedido na pergunta.